# How to create a matrix by averaging the elements of another matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I want to create a matrix (A) where its elements are the average of every four rows of another matrix (B). For example, the elements of row 1 in matrix A should be the averages of row 1 to 4 in matrix B. Currently I have used a loop function to get that but the size of the matrices are so large and that makes the loop very time consuming. I wonder if there is a better way to do that. Here is an example

```
B = matrix(runif(10000, 0, 10), 100, 100)
A = matrix(0, floor(dim(B)[1]/4), dim(B)[2])
for (im in 1: floor(dim(B)[1]/4)){
    A[im, ] = colMeans(as.matrix(B[c((((im - 1)*4) + 1):(im*4)), ]))
}
```

Comment: Your code is pretty efficient. I would guess that for a great improvement you will need to rewrite it using `Rcpp` package or something similar.

Answer (score 5):

You could vectorize this pretty easily using the `rowsum` function which has a `matrix` method (its' default) and can calculate sums by group. Then, just divide by 4 in order to get the means

```
grps <- floor(dim(B)[1]/4)
rowsum.default(B[1:(grps*4),], rep(1:grps, each = 4), reorder = FALSE)/4
```

---

**Benchmarks**

Since this is an optimization question here are some benchmarks with all the proposed methods on not such a big data set

```
library(zoo)
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(123)
B <- matrix(runif(100, 0, 10), 10000, 100)

OP <- function(B) {
  grps <- floor(dim(B)[1]/4)
  A = matrix(0, grps, dim(B)[2])
  for (im in 1: grps){
    A[im, ] = colMeans(as.matrix(B[c((((im - 1)*4) + 1):(im*4)), ]))
  }
  A
}

DA <- function(B){
  grps <- floor(dim(B)[1]/4)
  rowsum.default(B[1:(grps*4),], rep(1:grps, each = 4), reorder = FALSE)/4
}

JB <- function(B) as.matrix(aggregate(B, list(gl(ceiling(nrow(B)/4), 4, nrow(B))), mean)[, -1])

Thela <- function(B) tapply(B, list((row(B)-1) %/% 4,col(B)), FUN=mean)

RollApply <- function(B) rollapply(B, width = 4, by = 4, FUN = mean, by.column = TRUE)

microbenchmark(OP(B), DA(B), JB(B), RollApply(B), Thela(B), times = 10L)
# Unit: milliseconds
#         expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval  cld
#        OP(B)   45.57121   48.93491   70.17095   55.77107   65.43564   168.7760    10 a   
#        DA(B)   10.60941   10.87035   11.65232   11.36478   12.07908    14.1551    10 a   
#        JB(B) 1753.39114 1773.83230 1868.60788 1837.47161 1900.38141  2076.5835    10  b  
# RollApply(B) 8946.90359 9009.45160 9380.62408 9294.98441 9450.16426 10922.2595    10    d
#     Thela(B) 4820.36079 4925.70055 5117.22822 5048.89781 5257.58619  5650.2391    10   c
```

Turns out OPs solution isn't *so* bad after all.

Comment: Why `dim(B)[1]` instead of `nrow(B)` ?

Comment: @thelatemail it doesn't matter as far as Im concerned, I just don't like wrappers usually

Comment: @David. great thought on comparing the different methods.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with the following package (zoo)  and function (rollapply).

```
install.packages("zoo")
require(zoo)

  B <- matrix(runif(100, 0, 10),10, 10)
# with for loop
A = matrix(0,floor(dim(B)[1]/4),dim(B)[2])
for (im in 1 : floor(dim(B)[1]/4)){
+   A[im,] = colMeans(as.matrix(B[c((((im-1)*4)+1):(im*4)),]))}
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]
[1,] 5.633970 4.092848 3.793473 5.437288 6.316069 4.714015 5.837214 7.150007 4.638332
[2,] 5.445271 2.024052 6.096939 6.165723 3.049140 4.928087 5.433291 5.674594 4.607373
        [,10]
[1,] 5.260153
[2,] 6.589873

# with rowsum @ David
C = grps <- floor(dim(B)[1]/4)
rowsum(B[1:(grps*4),], rep(1:grps, each = 4))/4
      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]
1 5.633970 4.092848 3.793473 5.437288 6.316069 4.714015 5.837214 7.150007 4.638332
2 5.445271 2.024052 6.096939 6.165723 3.049140 4.928087 5.433291 5.674594 4.607373
     [,10]
1 5.260153
2 6.589873

# With rollapply 
D = rollapply(B, width = 4, by = 4, FUN = mean, by.column = T)
D
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]
[1,] 5.633970 4.092848 3.793473 5.437288 6.316069 4.714015 5.837214 7.150007 4.638332
[2,] 5.445271 2.024052 6.096939 6.165723 3.049140 4.928087 5.433291 5.674594 4.607373
        [,10]
[1,] 5.260153
[2,] 6.589873
```

Comment: `by.column = TRUE` is the default so it need not be provided.

Answer (score 1):

`aggregate` can do this too, but requires subsequent coercion to a `matrix`:

```
as.matrix(aggregate(B, list(gl(ceiling(nrow(B)/4), 4, nrow(B))), mean)[, -1])
```

Note that if `nrow(B)` isn't a multiple of 4, the result will include a final row that contains the column averages of the last `nrow(B) %% 4` rows.

---

As [indicated by @thelatemail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754786/how-to-create-a-matrix-by-averaging-the-elements-of-another-matrix-in-r/34755278?noredirect=1#comment57257642_34755278), `tapply` can do a neater job of this:

```
tapply(B, list((row(B)-1) %/% 4,col(B)), FUN=mean)
```

Comment: This doesn't give exactly the same result as OPs when `nrow(B)/4` isn't an integer.

Comment: @DavidArenburg - fair point. I figured it was probably fair to assume, for the OP's application, the number of rows would be a multiple of 4. Fixed now.

Comment: You will still need to remove last row :) Compare for `B <- matrix(runif(100, 0, 10),10, 10)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg - now _you're_ assuming that the OP wants to discard rows with less than 4 group members. ;)

Comment: I'm not assuming. This is what his code does. I'm just comparing to his results.

Comment: @DavidArenburg - I guess these are questions for the OP - the fact that incomplete groups aren't mentioned in the post suggests to me that either they won't happen with his real data, or that the OP hasn't thought of the possibility.

Comment: `tapply(B, list((row(B)-1) %/% 4,col(B)), FUN=mean)` or something similar would avoid the need to `as.matrix` - speed seems comparable.